# Add <pre> tag button in TinyMce 4

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm tying to add code into a tinymce textarea and I'm planning to hightlight it using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

In order to to so, I just need to wrap the code between the tags `<pre></pre>` and highlight.js will do the rest.

I tried using the [code plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/) in tinymce, which opens a popup where the user can paste the code. But to my surprise it does actually **nothing** with that text. It only allows you to see the HTML code for it, which will basically just show the text between `</p>` tags.

I would prefer not to use [codesample plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/) because I just want to add the `pre` tag and do not apply any codesample styles to it. I do not want either to have a list of languages to select from or to treat the whole code text as a block that has to be removed in a whole.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you want a dialog where someone can paste in some HTML and you will wrap that in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags as you insert the content into the editor.

There is not a plugin in TinyMCE that does precisely what you want.  You are correct that the codesample plugin is more complex than that (it uses something called Prism.js to handle syntax coloring and highlighting).

You can do one of two things:

- Look at how plugins like `codesample` and `template` create their dialogs (they use `windowManager`) and then you could make your own plugin that takes the user's input and wraps it in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags as its inserted into the editor.
- Add a toolbar button or menu item via the TinyMCE init and have that code open a dialog (via `windowManager`) and insert the content into the editor.

If you prefer the first option, using one of TinyMCE's existing templates as a starting point will save you a bit of coding time and show you a good example of how to use `windowManager`.

Here is an overly simply example of how you might use `windowManager` in the init:

```
 tinymce.init({
    ...  
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.addButton('insertusername', {
            text: 'Insert User Name',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function () {
                var person = {
                    firstname: '',
                    lastname: ''
                };
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Insert User Name - Custom Dialog',
                    body: [
                        {
                            type: 'textbox',
                            name: 'firstname',
                            label: 'First Name:',
                            value: '',
                            minWidth: 800,
                            value: person.firstname,
                            oninput: function() {
                                person.firstname = this.value();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'textbox',
                            name: 'lastname',
                            label: 'Last Name',
                            value: '',
                            minWidth: 800,
                            value: person.lastname,
                            oninput: function() {
                                person.lastname = this.value();
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {
                        // console.log('onSubmit called');
                        editor.insertContent('<span class="abc">'+ person.firstname + ' ' + person.lastname + '</span> ');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: I find the documentation quite lacking of examples and not very precise. Reading about the [`windowManager`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce.windowmanager/) I'm not able to find any good explanation of how to do it. And descriptions like `contains things like width/height/url etc.` doesn't help at all...

Comment: Where can I get the description of the object content?

Comment: Admitedly the docs are not very detailed - the best thing to do is look at other plugins that do what you want and adapt that code.  That is how I have created windowManager solutions in the past as multiple TinyMCE plugins rely on windowManager.